# Find the name of the current interactive shell in Rust

Tags: shell, rust

I'm trying the get the name of the current interactive shell that my command-line program is being executed on. In my terminal, I can run this command:

```
λ ps -p $$ -o 'comm='
zsh
```

And it correctly prints the name of the shell. If I run it with `sh -c`, same results:

```bash
λ sh -c "ps -p $$ -o 'comm='"
zsh
```

Trying it with Bash, same results:

```bash
λ bash
amir@shabani:~/Code/ami$ ps -p $$ -o 'comm='
bash
amir@shabani:~/Code/ami$ sh -c "ps -p $$ -o 'comm='"
bash
```

Now when I execute the same command in a Rust program, it prints `sh`.

```rust
use std::process::{Command, ExitCode};

pub fn shell() -> ExitCode {
    let output = Command::new("sh")
        .arg("-c")
        .arg("ps -p $$ -o 'comm='")
        .output()
        .expect("Failed to execute command");

    if output.status.success() {
        let shell_name = String::from_utf8_lossy(&output.stdout);
        println!("The current shell is: {}", shell_name.trim());
        ExitCode::SUCCESS
    } else {
        eprintln!("Error executing command");
        ExitCode::FAILURE
    }
}
```

No matter where I run the program, `zsh` or `bash`, it always prints `sh`. What's the problem?

Comment: `sh -c "ps -p $$ -o 'comm='"` in both bash and zsh will cause $$ to be expanded to the pid of the bash or zsh process. Try with `sh -c 'ps -p $$ -o "comm="'` which prevents expansion before it's passed to sh.

Comment: @thesilican Running `sh -c 'ps -p $$ -o "comm="'` prints `sh` in `zsh`. And you can't have strings in single quotes in Rust.

Comment: @AmirShabani The point is, that like when you don't expand you get the current process and not the wanted shell, so is in Rust where it is not expanded in time.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Oh I get it.

Comment: What you could do here is in your Rust code insert the parent PID of the rust process in place of the `$$`. Or, better, have rust do the work you're relying on `ps` for directly itself; there's no good reason to use `ps` here at all.

Comment: Anyhow -- there _is_ no problem here. Your command is starting `sh` and telling `sh` to put its own PID onto ps's command line, so _of course_ the output is `sh`; it can't possibly be anything else.

Comment: You aren't trying to support non-UNIX operating systems with this code -- do you need to support non-Linux operating systems? If not, you can just get the information directly out of procfs.

Comment: See https://docs.rs/nix/latest/nix/unistd/fn.getppid.html re: getting the PPID. Once you have that, you can put it on `ps`'s command line, or use [`read_link`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.read_link.html) to inspect `/proc/${ppid}/exe`.

Comment: Mind, _none_ of this code accomplishes your stated goal of finding the name of "the current interactive shell". Your existing command just finds the PID of the shell evaluating the `$$` expansion; it doesn't check whether that shell is interactive or not. If you wanted to find an _interactive_ shell you might walk the process tree and check whether `/proc/${pid}/fd/0` is connected to a TTY device; that's not perfect, but it's a more reliable indicator than what you're doing today. For that matter, there won't always _exist_ any interactive shell up the process tree at all.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Supporting non-UNIX systems isn't a priority, but eventually I'll try to support it. Thanks for the comments. Using `getppid` from `nix` in place of `$$` works.

Comment: Most shells will identify themselves in the `SHELL` environment variable, so just doing `echo "$SHELL"` (in the shell) or `println!("{}", std::env::var ("SHELL").unwrap_or_else (|_| "unknown".into()))` (in Rust) should do it.

Comment: @Jmb Yeah, that's the first thing I tried. In my case, the `SHELL` variable is empty.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to have *something* is to get the name of the parent process (the spawning process). This won't necessarily be the shell that spawned you: if you run the program via `cargo run`, for example, it will be Cargo. But if you run the program directly from the shell, it will be what you want.

You can use the [`sysinfo`](https://docs.rs/sysinfo) crate to get the parent process in a cross-platform manner:

```rust
fn main() {
    let system = sysinfo::System::new_with_specifics(
        sysinfo::RefreshKind::new().with_processes(sysinfo::ProcessRefreshKind::new()),
    );
    let my_pid = sysinfo::get_current_pid().expect("unable to get PID of the current process");
    let parent_pid = system
        .process(my_pid)
        .expect("no self process?")
        .parent()
        .expect("unable to get parent process");
    let parent_process = system
        .process(parent_pid)
        .expect("unable to get parent process");
    let parent_name = parent_process.name();

    println!("Spawning shell (or not): {parent_name}");
}
```

If you want more precise analysis, you can start from enumerating all living shell processes, and asking for their children *recursively*. If your process is in the list, that means it was spawned (directly or indirectly) from this shell.

Note that this only work if the shell is still alive; it won't work if it exited.